# Did I choose a good typeface to accompany my logo?

Tags: logo, critique, typefaces, calligraphy

I have a logo (the swan) and need to choose a font to accompany it. I would like to make two logos:

1. One where the company name is under the swan logo.
   [image]
2. Another one where the swan size is similar to the font size.
   [image]

I am not sure if the chosen typeface is a good decision. I am afraid the typeface is not readable enough.

Comment: It is pretty hard to read. And the two extra circles on the capital Fs are a bit distracting to me.

Comment: Also see [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57620/aligning-letters-wrong-appears-more-right/57712#57712) in regards to the sizing of your swan. It should probably be a little bigger in the second design.

Comment: Can you guys recommend a better font?

Comment: This logo simply isn't my "style". So, I won't comment a great deal on it. I will only add that I like the simplicity of the swan (I don't even think you need the eyebrow) -- the type is a direct contradiction to that simplicity.

Comment: If you keep the eyebrow.. I'd simply make it white rather than black.

Comment: The "eyebrow" meant to be closed eyes, eyelashes :) Bashful swan. The white color is a good idea.

Comment: My client wants the company name under the logo and I cant decide about the Font.

Answer (score 1):

Your swan logo and the typeface only match in one aspect and that is featuring round forms. Your logo is simplistic, while your typeface is ornamental. Your logo features flat solid shapes, while your typeface is more delicate, having a lot of thin strokes. Your logo expresses calmness, while your typeface expresses motion. Your logo says *constructed,* while your typeface says *handdrawn.*

What you need is probably a sans-serif display typeface with rounded features that comes with a good bolder variant (to have flat, solid shapes), that is not too prominent. None of these are solid requirements, but such a typeface is most likely to fulfil your needs. Just to exemplify this, here is your logo done with a fake-bold [Sofadi One](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/sofadi-one):

[image: Logo with Sofadi One]

Mind that this is just the result of a quick search and certainly not the best choice. You can probably find something that is similar with a true bold style, less straight *F, b,* and *i,* and a more calm *n, s,* and *e.*

Comment: I'd also add to take a look at [What font characteristics are associated with luxury and wealth](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53711/what-font-characteristics-are-associated-with-luxury-and-wealth).